# replace part of the url from a few cells in a CSV file in each row

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have the below CSV file. I would like to be able to convert it so I have IDs without URLs.

```
tID,type,usageID,Usage,status,tStatus,proParte,sName,snID,canName,scAuth,pnuID,tRank,trSort,King,class,subclass,family,created,modified,datasetName,tcID,Ref,refID,tRemarks,tDist,hClass,fhpName,fhpnID,shpn,shpnID,nomCode,Lic,ccaID
https://some-url.com/tree/90000607/90000610,scientific,https://some-url.com/tree/90000607/90000610,Bacteria,,accepted,f,Bacteria,https://some-url.com/name/bbni/90000608,Bacteria,,,Regnum,10,Bacteria,,,,2018-12-06 14:48:14.395+11,2018-12-06 14:48:14.708+11,BBC,https://some-url.com/instance/bbni/90000609,TWD,https://some-url.com/reference/bbni/90000596,,,Bacteria,,,,,ABC,-,/tree/90000607/90000610
```

I would like to accomplish the following one of two outcomes. I have tried different things using `sed piping` it through a few times, but I am unable to do it in one command using `regEx`.

*Option 1:*

```
tID,type,usageID,Usage,status,tStatus,proParte,sName,snID,canName,scAuth,pnuID,tRank,trSort,King,class,subclass,family,created,modified,datasetName,tcID,Ref,refID,tRemarks,tDist,hClass,fhpName,fhpnID,shpn,shpnID,nomCode,Lic,ccaID
tree/90000607/90000610,scientific,tree/90000607/90000610,Bacteria,,accepted,f,Bacteria,name/bbni/90000608,Bacteria,,,Regnum,10,Bacteria,,,,2018-12-06 14:48:14.395+11,2018-12-06 14:48:14.708+11,BBC,instance/bbni/90000609,TWD,reference/bbni/90000596,,,Bacteria,,,,,ABC,-,/tree/90000607/90000610
```

*Option 2:*

```
tID,type,usageID,Usage,status,tStatus,proParte,sName,snID,canName,scAuth,pnuID,tRank,trSort,King,class,subclass,family,created,modified,datasetName,tcID,Ref,refID,tRemarks,tDist,hClass,fhpName,fhpnID,shpn,shpnID,nomCode,Lic,ccaID
90000610,scientific,90000610,Bacteria,,accepted,f,Bacteria,90000608,Bacteria,,,Regnum,10,Bacteria,,,,2018-12-06 14:48:14.395+11,2018-12-06 14:48:14.708+11,BBC,90000609,TWD,90000596,,,Bacteria,,,,,ABC,-,90000610
```

If someone can assist with what you have done before, it would help me out.

**Things I Tried:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/[a-z]*:\/\/[a-z]*.[a-z]*.[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[a-z]*\/[a-z]*//g' BBC-taxon-2019-03-26-4546.csv > test.csv
sed -e 's/[0-9]\/[0-9]/[0-9]|[0-9]/g' test.csv
```

Above code needs to to write a command for each type of replacement and create a new file each time, so I gave up.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set Input File here...
input="BBC-taxon-2019-03-26-4546.csv"

# Check if file exists
[ ! -f $input ] && { echo "No file with name: $input. File not found"; exit 123; }

# Set file separator and read fields into variables
while IFS=',' read -ra fields;
do
  echo "Fields: ${fields[*]}"
  echo "Number of Elements: ${#fields[@]}"
  echo "Each Element has: ${#fields}"
  for i in "${fields[@]}"
  do
    echo $i
  done

#  fields[0] = ${fields[0]} 
done < "$input"
```

The above code creates a iterable array but I don't know how I can use `sed` on each value cell for a certain column. If anyone can help, that is great.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit which value (or part of string) you want to be removed (or to be replaced with what ) it is a really long string and by seeing the option 1 and 2, the value `90000607` for example is not found in the original string, so is it supposed to be result of some replacement?

Comment: Please check now. Sorry, copy paste problem.

Comment: Are the url always located at the same location in the csv? Same column?

Comment: Should other fields contain slashes? If not, `sed 's/[^,]*\//g' file` will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
tID,type,usageID,Usage,status,tStatus,proParte,sName,snID,canName,scAuth,pnuID,tRank,trSort,King,class,subclass,family,created,modified,datasetName,tcID,Ref,refID,tRemarks,tDist,hClass,fhpName,fhpnID,shpn,shpnID,nomCode,Lic,ccaID
https://some-url.com/tree/90000607/90000610,scientific,https://some-url.com/tree/90000607/90000610,Bacteria,,accepted,f,Bacteria,https://some-url.com/name/bbni/90000608,Bacteria,,,Regnum,10,Bacteria,,,,2018-12-06 14:48:14.395+11,2018-12-06 14:48:14.708+11,BBC,https://some-url.com/instance/bbni/90000609,TWD,https://some-url.com/reference/bbni/90000596,,,Bacteria,,,,,ABC,-,/tree/90000607/90000610
```

For **option 1** use:

```
sed -E 's@(https?://[^,/]+)?(/[^/]+/[^/]+/[0-9]+)@\2@g' input.csv 
tID,type,usageID,Usage,status,tStatus,proParte,sName,snID,canName,scAuth,pnuID,tRank,trSort,King,class,subclass,family,created,modified,datasetName,tcID,Ref,refID,tRemarks,tDist,hClass,fhpName,fhpnID,shpn,shpnID,nomCode,Lic,ccaID
/tree/90000607/90000610,scientific,/tree/90000607/90000610,Bacteria,,accepted,f,Bacteria,/name/bbni/90000608,Bacteria,,,Regnum,10,Bacteria,,,,2018-12-06 14:48:14.395+11,2018-12-06 14:48:14.708+11,BBC,/instance/bbni/90000609,TWD,/reference/bbni/90000596,,,Bacteria,,,,,ABC,-,/tree/90000607/90000610
```

For **option 2** use:

```
sed -E 's@(https?://[^,]+|(/[^,/]+)+)/([0-9]+)@\3@g' input.csv 
tID,type,usageID,Usage,status,tStatus,proParte,sName,snID,canName,scAuth,pnuID,tRank,trSort,King,class,subclass,family,created,modified,datasetName,tcID,Ref,refID,tRemarks,tDist,hClass,fhpName,fhpnID,shpn,shpnID,nomCode,Lic,ccaID
90000610,scientific,90000610,Bacteria,,accepted,f,Bacteria,90000608,Bacteria,,,Regnum,10,Bacteria,,,,2018-12-06 14:48:14.395+11,2018-12-06 14:48:14.708+11,BBC,90000609,TWD,90000596,,,Bacteria,,,,,ABC,-,90000610
```

add the option `-i.bak` to change directly the input file (inline mode) a backup file will be taken `.bak`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that each thing you are trying to parse is a url, and it wont conflict with other data fields, why not regex for the exact url string? like this:

```
sed -e 's/http[s]:\/\/.*\.com//g' test.csv
```

Comment: Urls have different string in them.

`https://some-url.com/tree/90000607/90000610`
`https://some-url.com/name/bbni/90000608`
`https://some-url.com/instance/bbni/90000609`
`https://some-url.com/reference/bbni/90000596`

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed
1st line not print tree and number, 2nd one print it because it has \1 at replace.

```
sed -Ez 's#\bhttps://[^/]+/tree/\w+/##g ' d
sed -Ez 's#\bhttps://[^/]+(/tree/\w+/)#\1#g ' d
```